# É obrigado settar um state pra todos os eventos?

Tags: react

Bom minha dúvida pode ser um pouco leiga, mas de qualquer forma é algo que me deixou curioso.
Eu sou obrigado a setar um state pra todos os eventos na tela?
Deixa eu tentar explicar melhor...
Eu tenho uma lista de usuários que eu retorno de uma API, pra cada usuário eu mostro o id, nome e o tipo de usuário(admin, etc.). Só que eu tenho duas funcionalidades nessa lista a de desativar o usuário e de editar ele, quando eu clico pra editar eu chamo uma função que pega o id e o valor "flex", nessa função eu pego q div que possuí o id usando a api do javascript de manipular a DOM e dou um style.display = value(que é "flex" ou "none").
Isso é uma boa prática? Ou eu teria que settar um state pra dar o toggle e se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso.

Comment: errado fazer assim: `style.display = value(que é "flex" ou "none")`

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: falta você postar um exemplo minimo do seu código

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisada, e vi que eu tinha que criar um componente separado para o que vai ser percorrido. Eu fiz e deu certo, consigo fazer o toggle de de uma forma mais limpa. Eu acabei separando em 3 componente s o que era só 1